# Plot multiple solutions of a system of differential equations with different values of constant c by using NDsolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, color

I am traying to solve system of differential equations with different values of constant c then plot the solution with different values of the constant c.
where c= 2.2758, 2.04822, 1.82064, 1.59306, 1.36548
So what i want is plot a variety of different graphs over the range of c and if it possible to get each graphs with different color.

my code

```
Clear[t]
τ = 13.8;
ω0 = 1;
r = 0.7071;
ℏ = 1.05457173*10^-34;
k = 1666666.667;
z = 0;
Ω = 2.2758;
τ = 13.8;
T2 = 200;
Δ = 1.7758;
ω = 0.5;
Table[c {c, {2.2758, 2.04822, 1.82064, 1.59306, 1.36548}}];

 system1 = {u'[t] == Δ*v[t], 
 v'[t] == -Δ*u[t] -c*E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - ((t^2*(1.177^2))/τ^2))*w[t], 
 w'[t] == c*E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - ((t^2*(1.177^2))/τ^2))*v[t]};
initialvalues1 = {u[-20] ==  0, v[-20] ==  0, w[-20] == -  1};
sol1 = NDSolve[Join[system1, initialvalues1], {u[t], v[t], w[t]}, {t, -20, 20}];

F = (-10^33*c*ℏ*r*u[t])/ω0^2*E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - ((t^2*(1.177^2))/τ^2));
P = Plot[Evaluate[F /. sol1], {t, -20, 20}, FrameLabel -> {"t(fs)", "FT"},
Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, FrameTicks -> All]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: All your questions seem strongly related, but you've been posting under other user handle before: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9850/saysics

Comment: Under that old handle you never voted and never accepted an answer. I hope you'll become a better citizen now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that much of what you've posted doesn't work in its present form but it can be simplified greatly in a working form. I've highlighted the key changes that need to be made (with some explanation) and then have put it all together at the end.

### Highlights

I'm not sure what you were trying to do using `Table` to generate the c values, but it seems that the simplest way would be to just include the values you want in a list like so:

```
cVals = {2.2758, 2.04822, 1.82064, 1.59306, 1.36548};
```

The next step is to solve the system of differential equations for different values of the parameter *c*. Since each of these functions *u,v*, and *w* are dependent on t, this is a good task for Mathematica's built in function `ParametricNDSolveValue`. There's a lot of great information in the [official documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) for doing the type of thing you want to do. The key here is that you define *c* to be the parameter that varies between solutions.

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[Join[system1,initialvalues1],{u,v,w},{t,-20,20},{c}];
```

At the end of the day, it appears that the function *F* is really what is needed. We can define it as a function of *c* as follows.

```
F[t_,c_]:=With[{val = First@pfun[c][t]}, (-10^33*c*ℏ*r*val)/ω0^2*E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - ((t^2*(1.177^2))/τ^2))];�������������������
```

The `val=First@pfun[c][t]` tells Mathematica that you want to evaluate the function u for a certain value of *c* and *t*. If you wanted to instead evaluate the value of `v` or `w` you would change `First@` to `Second@` or `Third@` respectively because that's the order of variables given in `pfun` above.

Finally, the solutions for the desired values of *c* can be plotted. Here is where you want to use `Table` to plot solutions for each of the *c* values.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[F[t, c], {c, cVals}]], {t, -20, 20},PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All,FrameLabel -> {"t(fs)", "FT"}]�
```

### Final Solution

All that's left now is to put it all together!

```
Clear[t]
(* define some constants *)
τ = 13.8;
ω0 = 1;
r = 0.7071;
ℏ = 1.05457173*10^-34;
k = 1666666.667;
z = 0;
Ω = 2.2758;
τ = 13.8;
T2 = 200;
Δ = 1.7758;
(* define the values of c *)
cVals = {2.2758, 2.04822, 1.82064, 1.59306, 1.36548};
(* define system of equations *)
system1 = {u'[t] == Δ*v[t], v'[t] == -Δ*u[t] -c*E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - ((t^2*(1.177^2))/τ^2))*w[t], w'[t] == 
c*E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - ((t^2*(1.177^2))/τ^2))*v[t]};
initialvalues1 = {u[-20] == 0, v[-20] == 0, w[-20] == -1};
(* compute the solution *)
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[Join[system1, initialvalues1], {u, v, w}, {t,-20, 20}, {c}];
F[t_, c_] := With[{val = First@pfun[c][t]}, (-10^33*c*ℏ*r*val)/ω0^2*E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - ((t^2*(1.177^2))/τ^2))];
(* plot the solutions for the different c values *)
Plot[Evaluate[Table[F[t, c], {c, cVals}]], {t, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, FrameLabel -> {"t(fs)", "FT"}]
(* celebrate! *)
```

Mathematica gladly produces this:

[image]

You can also get a legend for the plot with the optional `Plot` argument:

```
PlotLegends->Map[ToString,cVals]
```

Comment: thanks alot in is clear , But the function F in term of u[t] not c so how I can write it ,I try this F[t_, c_]:= With[{val = First@pfun[c][t]}, (-10^33*[HBar]*ru[t])/[Omega]0^2*E^(-(r^2/[Omega]0^2) - ((t^2*(1.177^2))/[Tau]^2))]; (*plot the solutions for the different c values) Plot[Evaluate[Table[F[t, c] /. pfun, {c, cVals}]], {t, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, FrameLabel -> {"t(fs)", "FT"}] –

Comment: The idea is that the particular solution for u depends on the value of c, so while it is true that F is a function of u, F is a function of c because u depends on c.. If what you need is the function u explicitly, you can get this by defining u[c_,t_]:=First@pfun[c][t].