# Plotting interpolating functions from ParametricNDSolveValue?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm looking at the behavior of a system of ODEs as a function of a parameter.

This is a system of phase oscillators, with the dynamics (simplified for clarity of reading, proper code farther below):

```
Phi'[m][t] == Freq + Sin[Phi[m + 1][t] - Phi[m][t] - p]
```

I want to look at the difference between two dynamic variables (for example, `Phi[m+1]-Phi[m]`) as a function of the parameter, `p`. I know how to look at the behavior of the *first* dynamic variable as a function of a parameter using `ParametricNDSolveValue` (the first Parameter Sweep problem under the Applications section of the help is similar to my approach, as is this Stack Exchange approach: [Plot multiple solutions of a system of differential equations with different values of constant c by using NDsolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69714/plot-multiple-solutions-of-a-system-of-differential-equations-with-different-val).)

```
(*system parameters*)
a = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}};
NatFreq = {1, .98, 1.02, 1.01};
InitCond[n_] := Array[Pi (# - 1)/(2) &, n]

(*ODEs and initial conditions*)
deqns = 
  Table[
    Phi[m]'[t] == 
      NatFreq[[m]] + Sum[a[[m,j]]*Sin[Phi[j][t] - Phi[m][t] - p],{j,4}],
   {m, 1, 4}]
ics = Table[Phi[m][0] == InitCond[4][[m]], {m, 1, 4}];

(*compute the solution*)
pfun1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{deqns, ics}, 
Table[Phi[m][t], {m, 1, 4}], {t, 0, 20}, {p}];
F[t_, p_] := With[{val1 = First[pfun1[p][t]]},val1];
```

So--I am able to plot `Phi[1][t]` for various parameters, `p`, with

```
pVals = {0, Pi/2, Pi, 3*Pi/2};
Plot[Evaluate[Table[F[t,p], {p, pVals}]],{t, 0, 20}]
```

I can't figure out how to access other dynamic variables, such as `Phi[2][t]`. `First[pfun1]`, best as I can tell, returns `Phi[1]`, `pfun1[[2]]` is not `Phi[2]`. How do I plot `Phi[2][t]`, or better yet, `Phi[2][t]-Phi[1][t]`?

Comment: Thanks all, useful link and two helpful examples.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this,

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun1[p] /. t -> x, {p, pVals}]], {x, 0, 20},PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Green, Blue},Frame -> True]
```

[image]

For this answer credit goes to @bbgodfrey for his [response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83040/trouble-with-parametricndsolvevalue) to same sort of question.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}};
NatFreq = {1, .98, 1.02, 1.01};
InitCond[n_] := Array[Pi (# - 1)/(2) &, n]

deqns = 
  Table[
    Phi[m]'[t] == 
      NatFreq[[m]] + Sum[a[[m, j]]*Sin[Phi[j][t] - Phi[m][t] - p], {j, 4}], 
    {m, 4}];
ics = Table[Phi[m][0] == InitCond[4][[m]], {m, 4}];
vars = Table[Phi[m], {m, 4}];

pF = ParametricNDSolveValue[{deqns, ics}, vars, {t, 0, 20}, {p}];
```

Now to get the individual interpolation functions for a given value of `p`, I define the function `pPhi`, where the 1st argument is the `Phi` index and 2nd argument is the parameter value.

```
pPhi[n : (1 | 2 | 3 | 4), p_?NumericQ] := pF[p][[n]]
```

Then to plot `Phi[2]` for your list of p-value, I write

```
pVals = {0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2};
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pPhi[2, p][t], {p, pVals}]], {t, 0, 20}]
```

and I get

plot[image]